# Create USB flash drive with two partitions: first to boot, second to store data - for Windows, not Linux

Tags: windows, bootable-media

I know this *should* be simple but I cannot for the life of me find info online about how to accomplish it. What I'm after is:

With a **32GB USB flash drive**
 1. Create small (1GB) FAT32 partition
 2. Create a larger 31GB ExFAT "Data" partition to store a .WIM file. < this is why I need a second partition: the WIM is 14 GB's too large to fit on FAT32.
 3. Write a bootable WinPE (Dell ImageAssist) ISO to the first, smaller partition
 4. The USB flash drive will be used to boot a machine, then take the .WIM file from  the "Data" partition and restore it to the machine's SSD.

I have tried using:
 - Rufus (no option to change formatting type, FAT32 only)
 - WinSetupFromUSB (works to make multi-boot ISO's on a single flash drive, but that's not what I need)

The machines will all be Dell Latitude laptops using UEFI. How can I get this done? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't see it mentioned in your question, however I would suggest trying maybe disk management tool. Try creating two separate partitions, one 1gb partition and one for whatever desired storage would be. not sure if related but one of our Microsoft devs also had to split his setup files one time in order to accomplish his goal when working with fat 32 file system. hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:
- Created the two partitions with **BootIce** program
- Manually copied the data in, extracted ISO to "boot" partition, WIM file to the larger "data" partition
- Used **EasyBCD** program to "Write MBR" to the "boot" partition